# identify groups of congruent points

Tags: python, performance, mathematics

I have two sets of points in lists list1 and list2 given below

```
list1 = [['a',[1.2,3.6,4.5]],['b',[3.2,-5.4,6.6]],['c',[1.1,2.2,9.9]],['d',[5.5,12.5,2.9]],['e',[3.5,6.5,22.9]]]
list2 = [['v',[11.2,3.6,4.5]],['x',[13.2,-5.4,6.6]],['y',[11.1,2.2,9.9]],['z',[15.5,12.5,2.9]]]
```

If all the points in list1 are rotated and/or translated, points `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` align with points `v`, `x`, `y` and `z` respectively. Currently I have written Python code that can output the groups of pairs provided two input lists using a pairwise distance comparison method. It computes intra-list combinatorial distances within `list1` and `list2` and compares these distances between the lists to identify the pairs. For e.g. `distance(ab) ~= distance(vx), distance(ac) ~= distance(vy)` and so on. The code is given below. My code works but is slow for larger lists. I would like to know if there is any faster or easier way to solve this problem.

Thanks

```
def calculate_distance(point1,point2):
        #function calculates distance
        dis = 0
        dis += math.pow((point2[0]-point1[0]),2)
        dis += math.pow((point2[1]-point1[1]),2)
        dis += math.pow((point2[2]-point1[2]),2)
        distance = math.sqrt(dis)
        return distance

def make_masterdict(list1,list2):
        # calculate interalist combinitorial pairs of points with
        # their distances and store into dicts
        list1pairs = {}
        list2pairs = {}
        for i in range(len(list1)):
                p1 = list1[i][1]
                for p2 in list1[i:]:
                    if list1[i][0] != p2[0]:
                        dist = calculate_distance(p1,p2[1])
                        #store both the pairs in the dictionary
                        list1pairs.update({list1[i][0]+'_'+p2[0]:dist})
                        list1pairs.update({p2[0]+'_'+list1[i][0]:dist})


        for i in range(len(list2)):
                p1 = list2[i][1]
                for p2 in list2[i:]:
                    if list2[i][0] != p2[0]:
                        dist = calculate_distance(p1,p2[1])
                        list2pairs.update({list2[i][0]+'_'+p2[0]:dist})
                        list2pairs.update({p2[0]+'_'+list2[i][0]:dist})

        # calculate interlist pairs between list1 and list2
        masterlist = []
        for i in list1:
                for j in list2:
                        masterlist.append([i[0],j[0]])

        masterdict = {}
        # for each combinatorial pair in masterlist
        for i in range(len(masterlist)-1):
                c1 = masterlist[i]
                key1 = c1[0]+'_'+c1[1]
                masterdict.update({key1:[]})
                for j in range(i+1,len(masterlist)):
                        c2 = masterlist[j]
                        # if the same point is not repeated in the pairs
                        if c1[0] != c2[0] and c1[1] != c2[1]:
                                #collect and compare the distances
                                p1 = c1[0]+'_'+c2[0]
                                p2 = c1[1]+'_'+c2[1]
                                dis1 = list1pairs[p1]
                                dis2 = list2pairs[p2]
                                if abs(dis1-dis2) < 0.1:
                                        #if same distance, then store in masterdict
                                        key2 = c2[0]+'_'+c2[1]
                                        masterdict[key1].append(key2)
        return masterdict                               

def recursive_finder(p1,list1,masterdict,d,ans):
        # if lenght of d is more than 2, store that list in ans
        if len(d) > 2:
                ans.append(d)

        # if lenght of list is 0, do not do anything
        if len(list1) == 0:
                pass
        else:
                other = []
                nextlist = []
                #loop through each value in list1 as p1
                for i in list1:
                        if i in masterdict[p1]:
                                #make empty list
                                newl = []
                                #store old group in newl
                                newl.extend(d)
                                #add new member to old group
                                newl.append(i)
                                #store this list
                                other.append(newl)
                                #store new member
                                nextlist.append(i)
                #repeat for each successful value in nextlist                
                for i in range(len(nextlist)):
                        #collect p1 and dnew 
                        p1 = nextlist[i]
                        dnew = other[i]
                        #repeat process
                        recursive_finder(p1,nextlist[i+1:],masterdict,dnew,ans)

def find_groups(list1,list2):
        #make master dictionary from input lists
        masterdict = make_masterdict(list1,list2)
        ans = []
        #use recursive function to identify groups
        for mainkey in masterdict:
                if len(masterdict[mainkey]) > 1:
                        for i in range(len(masterdict[mainkey])):
                                p1 = masterdict[mainkey][i]
                                recursive_finder(p1,masterdict[mainkey][i+1:],masterdict,[mainkey,p1],ans)

        return ans

#define two lists with a,b,c and d matching v,x,y, and z respectively
list1 = [['a',[1.2,3.6,4.5]],['b',[3.2,-5.4,6.6]],['c',[1.1,2.2,9.9]],['d',[5.5,12.5,2.9]],['e',[3.5,6.5,22.9]]]
list2 = [['v',[11.2,3.6,4.5]],['x',[13.2,-5.4,6.6]],['y',[11.1,2.2,9.9]],['z',[15.5,12.5,2.9]]]
answer = find_groups(list1,list2)
print(answer)
```

Upon running the code, the correct answer is output. Groups larger than size of 3 are output.

```
[['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y'], ['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y', 'd_z'], ['a_v', 'b_x', 'd_z'], ['a_v', 'c_y', 'd_z'], ['b_x', 'c_y', 'd_z']]
```

Comment: Can you provide simple examples of input and desired output?

Comment: input lists list1 and list2 are given in the beginning and output is given at the end of the question. list1 = [['a',[1.2,3.6,4.5]],['b',[3.2,-5.4,6.6]],['c',[1.1,2.2,9.9]],['d',[5.5,12.5,2.9]],['e',[3.5,6.5,22.9]]]
list2 = [['v',[11.2,3.6,4.5]],['x',[13.2,-5.4,6.6]],['y',[11.1,2.2,9.9]],['z',[15.5,12.5,2.9]]]. Output is [['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y'], ['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y', 'd_z'], ['a_v', 'b_x', 'd_z'], ['a_v', 'c_y', 'd_z'], ['b_x', 'c_y', 'd_z']]

Comment: How large would a "large" list be? Would it be possible to share an example of a large list, maybe using a GitHub gist or something similar?

Comment: Large lists refer to more than 10,000 points in list1 and list2

Answer (score 6):

## Calculate Distance

To check the distance between points, you can `zip` together two points to get corresponding coordinates. Every point is denoted by X, Y, Z, so `zip(point1, point2)` will give you pairs `(X1, X2), (Y1, Y2), (Z1, Z2)`. Furthermore, you can use `sum` to get the total of any iterable, rather than hard-coding indices. Applying this to your distance function:

```py
import math

def calculate_distance(p1, p2):
    """
    Takes the euclidean distance between two points. They are assumed
    to be of equal length:

        p1 = [a1, a2, ..., an]
        p2 = [b1, b2, ..., bn]

    Where n is any integer
    """
    sq_dist = sum((a - b)**2 for a, b in zip(p1, p2))
    return math.sqrt(sq_dist)
```

This allows you to handle any point, and cleanly pairs up corresponding points.

## Generating Combinations of Distances

There's no need to re-create a combinatorics function, one exists for you in [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). They also include a sample recipe if you want to try it on your own, but theirs is great. It has the added benefit that you don't store the combinations in memory by default, that's totally up to you.

It looks like you are trying to find pairs of points across both lists that share the same distance. You have *lots* of nested loops here, so let's look at it one step at a time. A `dict` is a great way to group these points together, with the keys being distance and the values being the pairs of points.

To keep track of where sets of points come from, we can return separate dictionaries for fast membership testing:

```py
def combine(l1, l2):
    """
    Create your master dictionary by using the dict
    constructor on the list of key: value pairs (key is str, val is list)
    """
    d = dict(l1)
    d2 = dict(l2)

    return d, d2
```

Ok, using itertools to generate pairs, you want to group based on the euclidean distance between points. Let's do that. We will use a `defaultdict` of `set` to hold our list of names based on a distance key. The `set` will make sure that the names pairs are unique:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations


def get_pairs(d1, d2):
    """
    p1 and p2 are dictionaries of points
    we will construct a defaultdict that will take the combinations
    of points and construct the euclidean distance as our key, and a set of
    names as the values
    """
    groups = defaultdict(set)

    # unpack the names and the points using dict.items()
    pairs_dict = {**d1,**d2}
    for (name1, p1), (name2, p2) in combinations(pairs_dict.items(), 2):
        check_1 = name1 in d1 and name2 in d1
        check_2 = name1 in d2 and name2 in d2
        if check_1 or check_2:
            # skip since they lie in the same dictionary
            continue
        dist = calculate_distance(p1, p2)

        for k in groups:
            # this will give you that tolerance you are looking for
            if math.isclose(dist, k, rel_tol=0.1):
                groups[k].add((name1, name2))
        groups[dist].add((name1, name2))

    return groups
```

Why do it this way? Well, you avoid most of your nested loops, and you are returned pairs of names based on the distances. The reason I say most is that you want to check against existing distances in your group dictionary to pair up approximately equal distances. Then you are grouping not only by exact distance, but also by approximate distance. Now, as the dictionary grows, this will be an O(N) operation, and you aren't necessarily going to avoid that. Add that to an O(M) loop, where M is the number of combinations, and N*M can get quite big, but comparing to your recursive function:

```py
def recursive_finder(p1,list1,masterdict,d,ans):
        # if lenght of d is more than 2, store that list in ans
        if len(d) > 2:
                ans.append(d)

        # if lenght of list is 0, do not do anything
        if len(list1) == 0:
                pass
        else:
                other = []
                nextlist = []
                #loop through each value in list1 as p1
                for i in list1:
                        if i in masterdict[p1]:
                                #make empty list
                                newl = []
                                #store old group in newl
                                newl.extend(d)
                                #add new member to old group
                                newl.append(i)
                                #store this list
                                other.append(newl)
                                #store new member
                                nextlist.append(i)
                #repeat for each successful value in nextlist                
                for i in range(len(nextlist)):
                        #collect p1 and dnew 
                        p1 = nextlist[i]
                        dnew = other[i]
                        #repeat process
 # can't get this to line up, indentation should be the same                     
 recursive_finder(p1,nextlist[i+1:],masterdict,dnew,ans)
```

You have a recursive function containing an O(N) loop inside another O(N) loop, so the O(M*N) is no worse than the existing code. Furthermore, while this may *look* like I'm modifying a dict while iterating over it, I'm really not. The state of the keys is constant while I iterate the keys, and I only inject a key after the loop. Your outer `build_master_dict` function, however, does modify a dict while iterating over the keys, since the recursive function is nested inside that loop.

This makes it *really* easy to look them up from your master dictionary:

```py
# assume list1 and list2 are the same and in the namespace already
import math
import json # for formatting
from collections import defaultdict

d1, d2 = combine(list1, list2)

groups = get_pairs(d1, d2)

# to look up your points
points = groups[5.579426493825329]

for p1, p2 in points:
    print(d[p1], d[p2])
[1.2, 3.6, 4.5] [1.1, 2.2, 9.9]
[11.2, 3.6, 4.5] [11.1, 2.2, 9.9]
```

Or, to show in a more succinct way:

```py
for dist, points in groups.items():
    print(dist)
    for p1, p2 in points:
        print(p1, d[p1], p2, d[p2])

9.455686120002081
a [1.2, 3.6, 4.5] b [3.2, -5.4, 6.6]
v [11.2, 3.6, 4.5] x [13.2, -5.4, 6.6]
5.579426493825329
a [1.2, 3.6, 4.5] c [1.1, 2.2, 9.9]
v [11.2, 3.6, 4.5] y [11.1, 2.2, 9.9]
...
```

It's now easy to filter `groups` by `len` as well:

```py
res = dict(filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) >= 3, groups.items()))

{10.0: {('c', 'y'), ('a', 'v'), ('b', 'x'), ('d', 'z'), ('d', 'v')}, 15.146286673637205: {('e', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('a', 'x'), ('d', 'y')}, 11.363538181394032: {('b', 'v'), ('b', 'y'), ('a', 'y'), ('c', 'v'), ('d', 'v')}, 12.223338332877807: {('c', 'v'), ('b', 'v'), ('b', 'y')}, 11.448143954370945: {('c', 'v'), ('d', 'v'), ('b', 'y')}, 22.03156826011258: {('e', 'z'), ('e', 'v'), ('e', 'x'), ('d', 'x'), ('b', 'z')}, 14.664924138910505: {('e', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('d', 'y')}, 19.03811965504997: {('e', 'v'), ('d', 'x'), ('c', 'z')}}
```

And to get your values:

````py
res = list(map(list, dict(filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) >= 3, groups.items())).values()))

[[('c', 'y'), ('a', 'v'), ('b', 'x'), ('d', 'z'), ('d', 'v')], 
 [('e', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('a', 'x'), ('d', 'y')], 
 [('b', 'v'), ('b', 'y'), ('a', 'y'), ('c', 'v'), ('d', 'v')], 
 [('c', 'v'), ('b', 'v'), ('b', 'y')],  
 [('c', 'v'), ('d', 'v'), ('b', 'y')], 
 [('e', 'z'), ('e', 'v'), ('e', 'x'), ('d', 'x'), ('b', 'z')], 
 [('e', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('d', 'y')], [('e', 'v'), ('d', 'x'), ('c', 'z')]]

# to format your keys:
pairs = [['_'.join(x) for x in sub] for sub in res]

[['c_y', 'a_v', 'b_x', 'd_z', 'd_v'], 
 ['e_y', 'c_x', 'a_x', 'd_y'], 
 ['b_v', 'b_y', 'a_y', 'c_v', 'd_v'], 
 ['c_v', 'b_v', 'b_y'], 
 ['c_v', 'd_v', 'b_y'], 
 ['e_z', 'e_v', 'e_x', 'd_x', 'b_z'], 
 ['e_y', 'c_x', 'd_y'], 
 ['e_v', 'd_x', 'c_z']]
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it's my mistake not explaining the problem properly. I need to identify groups of pairs that have equal intra-list distances. For example, if list1 = [['a',[0,0,0]],['b',[1,0,0]],['c',[0,3.5,0]]] and list2 = [['v',[0,0,5]],['x',[0,0,6]],['y',[0,3.5,5]]] then the solution will be [['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y']]. As you will notice, dis(a,b) = dis(v,x) , dis(a,c) = dis(v,y) and dis(b,c) = dis(x,y). If I had to identify a group of four pairs from much larger input lists, then I would need 6 distance equalities.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The edited version you provided still outputs the wrong answer for  list1 = [['a',[0,0,0]],['b',[1,0,0]],['c',[0,3.5,0]]] and list2 = [['v',[0,0,5]],['x',[0,0,6]],['y',[0,3.5,5]]]. The right answer is  [['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y']]. I think the issue is in the usage of distances as keys in the dictionary since the aim is not to identify groups that have the same inter-pair distance but inter-list pairs that have the same combinatiorial intra-pair distances.

Comment: Hm, I'm misunderstanding the question, then. I'll take some time with it. I'm not sure what you mean by *inter-list pairs that have the same combinatorial intra-pair distances*. Let's take your answer, `['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y']`. Putting it in simple language, is it that `a_v, b_x, and c_y` share a distance? What *exactly* do they share that causes them to be grouped? *inter-list pairs* implies pairs across the two lists while *intra-pair distances* implies the distance between the pair of points must be the same. Am I off base here?

Comment: I think I see the problem now, like I said, I'll take some time to revise it

Comment: For the solution, a_v, b_x and c_y means that the points in one list can be moved and/or rotated collectively to match those from other list. Hence 'a' would align/occupy/meet 'v', 'b' to 'x' and 'c' to 'y'. Without doing any actual movements or rotations, I am using pairwise distance checks to find the groups. Hence for the solution a_v, b_x and c_y, distance(a,b) = distance(v,x) , distance(a,c) = distance(v,y) and distance(b,c) = distance(x,y). Thanks for the continuing help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Pythonprotein Let me see if this phrasing of your question makes sense. You have a collection of points between two lists. A collection of three or more points is a plane, mathematically speaking. You want to know if there is a series of linear transformations that can be applied to a plane in `list1` to create a plane in `list2`? And this should list all such planes?

Comment: Though the *distance* requirement highlights only translations in this particular example

Comment: It does not need to be only three points (minimum of three) and not only linear transformations. For eg. for the input lists list1 = [['a',[0,0,0]],['b',[1,0,0]],['c',[0,3.5,0]]] and list2 = [['v',[0,0,5]],['x',[0,0,6]],['y',[0,3.5,5]]], both rotation and translation are involved to coincide points a to v, b to x and c to y. The first example I gave required only translations.

Answer (score 4):

### Sum generator

```
    dis = 0
    dis += math.pow((point2[0]-point1[0]),2)
    dis += math.pow((point2[1]-point1[1]),2)
    dis += math.pow((point2[2]-point1[2]),2)
```

can be

```
    dis = sum((p2 - p1)**2 for p1, p2 in zip(point1, point2))
```

### Type hints

PEP484 type hints will help the static analysis and readability of your code. For example,

```
def calculate_distance(point1: Sequence[float], point2: Sequence[float]) -> float:
```

### Variable naming

Never call anything `list1` or `list2`. What do the lists actually contain? What are they for? Are they full of license plates? Death certificates? Deeds to property on the moon?

### Typo

`interalist` = `intra-list`.

### Point tuples

From what I can tell, many of your sequences are actually three-dimensional points. There are easier or at least more legible ways to represent this, perhaps as a namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ('x', 'y', 'z'))
# ...
list1 = [['a', Point(1.2,3.6,4.5)] ...
```

### f-strings

`p2[0]+'_'+list1[i][0]`

can be

```
f'{p2[0]}_{list1[i][0]}'
```

or, if you use named tuples - and assuming that this is a `Point` -

```
f'{p2.x}_{list1[i].x}'
```

### Loop like a native

```
    for i in range(len(list1)):
            p1 = list1[i][1]
```

can become

```
for item1 in list1:
    p1 = item1[1]
```

In other words, don't use C-style indexing when you can just iterate over the items in an iterable.

### Use `isclose`

```
if abs(dis1-dis2) < 0.1:
```

is better represented with a call to [`isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose).

### Null conditions

Don't do this:

```
    if len(list1) == 0:
            pass
    else:
```

Just write

```
if len(list1) != 0:
    # ...
```

### List creation

This:

```
   #make empty list
   newl = []
   #store old group in newl
   newl.extend(d)
```

should simply be

```
new1 = list(d)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if list:` make more sense, since any list that is length 0 won't pass this check?

Comment: Depends on whether the OP also cares about `None` references, which are also falsy.

Answer (score 3):

## Indentation

Use four (4) spaces for indentation, not eight (8).

## Checking List Existence

This

```
if len(list1) == 0:
    pass
else:
```

should be this (Thanks to @Reinderien for pointing this out)

```
if list1:
    ...
```

## Parameter Spacing

There should be spaces between parameters and the commas. For example, from this

```
def recursive_finder(p1,list1,masterdict,d,ans):
```

to this

```
def recursive_finder(p1, list1, masterdict, d, ans):
```

## Type Hints

This allows you to show what functions are accepting/returning. These are added to function headers. For example, from this

```
def find_groups(list1, list2):
```

to this

```
def find_groups(list1: list, list2: list) -> list:
```

## String Formatting

Doing this

```
p1 = c1[0]+'_'+c2[0]
p2 = c1[1]+'_'+c2[1]
```

can be simplified using an `f""` stringike so

```
p1 = f"{c1[0]}_{c2[0]}"
p2 = f"{c1[1]}_{c2[1]}"
```

## Operator Spacing

This

```
dis += math.pow((point2[0]-point1[0]),2)
dis += math.pow((point2[1]-point1[1]),2)
dis += math.pow((point2[2]-point1[2]),2)
```

should be spaced out like this

```
dis += math.pow((point2[0] - point1[0]),2)
dis += math.pow((point2[1] - point1[1]),2)
dis += math.pow((point2[2] - point1[2]),2)
```

## Simplification

The above can even be reduced to one statement

```
dis = math.pow((point2[0] - point1[0]), 2) + \
      math.pow((point2[1] - point1[1]), 2) + \
      math.pow((point2[2] - point1[2]), 2)
```

The `\` allows the addition to span multiple lines, increasing readability.

Your `calculate_distance` function can now be reduced to one statement:

```
def calculate_distance(point1: list, point2: list) -> float:
    """
    Returns the distance between the two points
    """
    return math.sqrt(
        math.pow((point2[0] - point1[0]), 2) + \
        math.pow((point2[1] - point1[1]), 2) + \
        math.pow((point2[2] - point1[2]), 2)
    )
```

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks for the `if not` suggestion, I realize that's much better. And I used `line` and `statement` intermittently. I meant to use `statement` both times.

Comment: IMHO you should not need \ in `calculate_distance`, Python's implicit line continuation/joining should take care of this. [PEP 8 also recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) putting binary operators, e.g. `+`, at the beginning of the next line, not at the end of the last one.